# Fragment confusion.. Fragments in a ViewPager, trying to get Contacts-like navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

When I say Contacts-like, I mean like this:

- `ViewPager` with multiple pages
- One fragment has a list with clickable items
- When an item is clicked, show a details page for it

Currently, my list fragment works fine in the ViewPager, and my details fragment works fine too on its own.

I want to properly set up this flow, in a way that will later let me optimize it for tablets. Right now, just having it open a new screen with details is fine.

Here's my adapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    FragmentManager fm;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.fm = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Files.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return Files.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.files).toUpperCase();
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.transfers).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the part of my list fragment, where I want to bring up the details:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
            View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!file[position].isFolder) {
            I don't know what to do here!
        }
    }

});
```

How do I go about this?